# Data.frame of Data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe, recursion, assignment-operator, recursive-datastructures

I'm using a data.frame that contains many data.frames. I'm trying to access these sub-data.frames within a loop. Within these loops, the names of the sub-data.frames are contained in a string variable. Since this is a string, I can use the [,] notation to extract data from these sub-data.frames. e.g. `X <- "sub.df"`and then `df[42,X]` would output the same as `df$sub.df[42]`.

I'm trying to create a single row data.frame to replace a row within the sub-data.frames. (I'm doing this repeatedly and that's why my sub-data.frame name is in a string). However, I'm having trouble inserting this new data into these sub-data.frames. Here is a MWE:

```
#Set up the data.frames and sub-data.frames
sub.frame <- data.frame(X=1:10,Y=11:20)
df <- data.frame(A=21:30)
df$Z <- sub.frame
Col.Var <- "Z"

#Create a row to insert
new.data.frame <- data.frame(X=40,Y=50)

#This works:
df$Z[3,] <- new.data.frame

#These don't (even though both sides of the assignment give the correct values/dimensions):

df[,Col.Var][6,] <- new.data.frame #Gives Warning and collapses df$Z to 1 dimension

df[7,Col.Var] <- new.data.frame #Gives Warning and only uses first value in both places

#This works, but is a work-around and feels very inelegant(!)
eval(parse(text=paste0("df$",Col.Var,"[8,]  <- new.data.frame")))
```

Are there any better ways to do this kind of insertion? Given my experience with R, I *feel* like this should be easy, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: You can also do `df[[Col.Var]][3, ] <- new.data.frame`, but generally this is not a good way to arrange data in R, I guess.

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you like data.frames. So we put a data.frame in your data.frame so your can enjoy data.frames while you're working with data.frames....

Comment: Seriously though, this is a very complex structure. There are two good alternatives. A list of data.frames, or data.frames with list columns. I strongly recommend a list of data.frames as this structure is much easier to work with.

Comment: Even though this is a contrived example, I see no reason why this method of "nesting" frames would be necessary or even that useful. I second Brandon's comment, noting that *"data.frames with list columns"* is a method popularized by the `tidyr` package.